# debug horner's rule programme

Tags: c++, algorithm, compiler-errors

I am a beginner and totally confused.
I am getting two errors in my c++ code:

Program:32:5: error: redefinition of 'main'
Program:3:6: note: previous definition of 'main' was here

You are given a polynomial of degree n. The polynomial is of the form P(x) = anxn + an-1xn-1 + … + a0. For given values k and m, You are required to find P(k) at the end of the mth iteration of Horner’s rule. The steps involved in the Horner’s rule are given below,

Pn (x) = an

Pn-1 (x) = an-1 + x * Pn (x)                          1st iteration.

Pn-2 (x) = an-2 + x * Pn-1 (x)                        2nd iteration.

.

.

P0 (x) = a0 + x * P1 (x)                             nth iteration.

In general, Pi (x) = ai + x * Pi + 1 (x) and P0(x) is the final result. The input to your program is as follows,

Line 1 contains the integers n, m and k separated by space.

Line 2 contains the coefficients an, an-1…, a0 separated by space.

INPUT: Integers n, m, k and the coefficients as described above.

OUTPUT: P(k) value at the end of the mth iteration.

Sample Input:

```
2 2 5

3 2 1
```

Sample Output:

```
86
```

Constraints:

1 <= n, k, m <= 10

0 <= ai <=10

```
   #include <stdio.h>  
 #include <string.h>  
 int main() {  
   int num, i, j, result, index;  
   char name[11][11];   
   char temp[11];           
   scanf("%d\n", &num);  
   for(i = 0; i < num; i++)  
     scanf("%s\n", name[i]);  
   for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {   
     index = i;  
     for(j = i + 1; j < num; j++) {  
       result = strcmp(name[index], name[j]);  
       if(result > 0)                  
         index = j; 
         }  
     strcpy(temp, name[index]);  
     strcpy(name[index], name[i]);           
     strcpy(name[i], temp);  
   }  
   for(i = 0; i < num-1; i++) {  
     printf("%s", name[i]);  
     printf("\n");  
   }  
   printf("%s", name[num-1]);  
   return 0;  
 }  

#include<stdio.h>

int horner(int [], int, int);
int main()
{
    int n, m, k, i;
    int a[10];
    scanf("%d%d%d",&n,&m,&k);
    for (i=0; i<=n; ++i){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("%d",horner(a,m,k));
    return 0;
}

int horner(int a[], int m, int k){
    if (m==0){
        return a[m];
    }
    else{
        return a[m] + k * horner(a,m-1,k);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Program:32:5: error: redefinition of 'main'
```

In "Program", line 32, column 5, the identifier `main` is defined a second time in the same scope.

```
Program:3:6: note: previous definition of 'main' was here
```

The first definition was in "Program", line 3, column 6.

There you are. You cannot define the same function twice. There really is nothing to add.

---

Except perhaps:

- Use consistent indentation. Always four spaces is a good rule. Avoid tabulators if you can, they are *asking* for trouble.
- **Always** put `{}` around the blocks of `if`, `for`, and `while`, even if they are only one line. Personally, I even add them if the block is *empty*, adding a `// EMPTY` comment to make it explicit that the emptiness is not due to a simple typing error.
- Whitespace is free. It does not slow down your typing much, and it *does* make reading the source much easier. You *read* source **much** more often than typing it, so do yourself that favor.

---

Then there's Debugging 101:

- Cut away some source that doesn't look as if it's contributing to your problem (which, in this case, is "redefinition of 'main'", not Horner's Rule).
- Check if the problem persists.
- Cut away MORE source, until you find the ONE change that makes your error go away. Either the problem is now evident to you, *or* you have found a *minimal* example to post on something like StackOverflow.

You could have cut away basically everything and end up with:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Hmm... what seems to be the problem? Maybe I re-defined 'main()'? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The error message seems to have nailed the problem quite well. You've got two main functions.  You can only have one, so pick one and delete the other.